# Chat message displays in opposite order

Tags: php

I am developing a website where users can type message in a div.

This is the format  of the message which will be saved in the file `post_archieve.php`.

The problem is that the most recent message is on the bottom, and the oldest message is on the top of the div which is the opposite of what I intended.

How can I get the messages to appear in the correct order?

```php
$handle = fopen("post_archieve.php", "a") or die("error"); //deschid cu a ca sa pastreze continutul
$mesaj = $_POST['message'];
    
$timestamp = time()+ 60*60;
$Time = gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $timestamp);
$postare = '<p class="paragraf">'.$Time."<br>".$username."\r\n"." : ".$mesaj.'</p>';
     
fwrite($handle, $postare);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Append mode adds what you write to the end of the file. If you want to insert at the beginning, you need to read the entire file into a variable, concatenate that to the new data, and rewrite the file.

```
$mesaj = $_POST['message'];
    
$timestamp = time()+ 60*60;
$Time = gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $timestamp);
$postare = '<p class="paragraf">'.$Time."<br>".$username."\r\n"." : ".$mesaj.'</p>';

$contents = file_get_contents("post_archieve.php");
$contents = $postare . $contents;
file_put_contents("post_archieve.php", $contents);
```

Note also that your code is wide open to Cross-Site Scripting attacks. You should encode the message with:

```
$mesaj = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
```